# Jquery drag and drop multiple items without removing source items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two lists (div or table elements) in which I can drag & drop items from one to the other, and its working fine. But I want a to drop a copy of selected items form source div NOT removing it from the source list.
Any solution?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="demo">
    <p>Available Boxes (click to select multiple boxes)</p>    
    <ul id="draggable">
        <li>Box #1</li>
        <li>Box #2</li>
        <li>Box #3</li>
        <li>Box #4</li>
    </ul>

    <p>My Boxes</p>
    <ul id="droppable">
    </ul>

</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var selectedClass = 'ui-state-highlight',
        clickDelay = 600,
        // click time (milliseconds)
        lastClick, diffClick; // timestamps

    $("#draggable li")
    // Script to deferentiate a click from a mousedown for drag event
    .bind('mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
        if (e.type == "mousedown") {
            lastClick = e.timeStamp; // get mousedown time
        } else {
            diffClick = e.timeStamp - lastClick;
            if (diffClick < clickDelay) {
                // add selected class to group draggable objects
                $(this).toggleClass(selectedClass);
            }
        }
    })
    .draggable({
        revertDuration: 10,
        // grouped items animate separately, so leave this number low
        containment: '.demo',
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass(selectedClass);
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            // reset group positions
            $('.' + selectedClass).css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            });
        },
        drag: function(e, ui) {
            // set selected group position to main dragged object
            // this works because the position is relative to the starting position
            $('.' + selectedClass).css({
                top: ui.position.top,
                left: ui.position.left
            });
        }
    });

    $("#droppable, #draggable").sortable().droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            $('.' + selectedClass).appendTo($(this)).add(ui.draggable) // ui.draggable is appended by the script, so add it after
            .removeClass(selectedClass).css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Live Link: http://jsfiddle.net/T68Fn/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clone node on drag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623703/clone-node-on-drag)

Comment: any soln form anyone - how to clone?

Comment: Did you check the link in my comment?

Comment: yeah I check it Dekel but I not understand. can you please help me to implement in my code..?

Comment: I have added $('.' + selectedClass).clone().appendTo($(this)).add(ui.draggable).....

Comment: but when i try to move in another div its copied on same div and also not clear the section on selected items

Comment: There are two parts there that you need. The first one is the helper and the second one is clone of the dragged element. Check the example in the link I gave.